# Php - reading and matching strings from a file

Tags: php

I am writing php to verify login credentials where the credentials (user,pass) is stored in a txt file:
The text file has an empty line at the end.

users.txt

```
BobRock123,password123
DouglasFerm553,secret642
SallyHomes,Yse3qs
Vinny893,street3r2
```

php

```
$userFile = fopen("users.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
while (!feof($userFile) && fgets($userFile) != "")
{
     $line = explode(",", fgets($userFile));
     if ($username == $line[0] && $password == $line[1])
     {
          header("Location:  nextpage.php");
          exit;
     }
}
```

I am not able to redirect to nextpage.php even trying with matching username and passwords (all matching username and passwords fail).
If I replace the `if` line with `if (true)`, I will be redirected, confirming that I am able to open my file.

Comment: `fgets()` will normally have the *new line* from the file on the end of the string, so it will be trying to match the password with the password plus some whitespace.  Using `trim(fgets($userFile))` should solve the problem.

Comment: @NigelRen, that didn't work.

Comment: Have you corrected the various other bugs in your code - missing comma in `explode("," fgets($userFile))`, missing `;` on the `header` line.  You also use `fgets` in the loop and the explode - so reading two lines per loop.  Change loop to `while (!feof($userFile) && ($line = fgets($userFile)) != "")` and explode to `explode(",", trim($line))`